# Which debugger use with .NET 4.0

Tags: c#

I'm running .NET 4, have Visual Studio 2012 and I compiled
a program by csc with debug flag.
However when I run mdbg I have an error: the debugger protocol is incompatible with debug object Exception HRESULT  0x8013134B.
So, is mdbg incompatible with .NET 4.0 and there is another debugger?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3836269/debugging-vs-2005-prompts-an-operation-not-supported *This error occurs when there is a CLR version mismatch between what the debugger is expecting and what is actually running in the debuggee process.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using an old version of MDbg, it can only work with the CLR v2.0.50727 debugger interfaces.  Which were updated for CLR v4.0.30319, the CLR version for .NET 4.0 and .NET 4.5.

You can download it [CLR Managed Debugger (mdbg) Sample 4.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2282)

Comment: The link seems to be gone now, pointing to https://www.microsoft.com/library/errorpages/smarterror.aspx for me.

Answer (score 3):

Could it be a path issue. What version of MDBG are you running. If you runn it with no params it should spit out some version info.

```
MDbg (Managed debugger) v4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100) started.
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

Comment: MDbg (Managed debugger) v3.5.30729.1 (SP.030729-0100) started.
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Comment: that's your problem right there... you need to run the correct version of MDBG. If you open the Visual Studio 2010 Command Prompt, it should set your `%PATH%` up correctly to use the v4.x version

Comment: looks like your running `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\Mdbg.exe` instead of `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\Mdbg.exe`

Comment: No, it does not work! My csc output this version info: 4.0.30319.17929 .NET Framework 4.5 but from NETFX 4.0 directory mdbg output this version info: 4.0.30319.1. In fact if I launch mdbg it outputs something like this: request not supported - HRESULT exception 0x80070032.